# When we should use <dl> over <ul>?

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c, semantic-markup, screen-readers

In what scenarios we should go for `<dl>` not `<ul>`?

Does it matter for screen reader user `<ul>` or `<dl>`? does screen reader software notify user about content is in `<ul>` or `<dl>`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A `<dl>` is a definition list. It should be used in such a case as, perhaps, a dictionary:

Use-case:

```
<dl>
<dt>Thesaurus</dt>
<dd>A book for finding synonyms of other words, often alphabetical. Similar to a dictionary.</dd>
</dl>
```

Result of the above:

Thesaurus

A book for finding synonyms of other words, often alphabetical. Similar to a dictionary.

---

The idea being that the term-to-be-defined is held in the `<dt>` element, and the definition of that term is given in the `<dd>`.

A `<ul>` is an unordered list. Now, a `<dl>` does not imply any order to its contents, but it does imply a semantic relation between its children. A `<ul>`, however, could contain anything that is not ordered.

Comment: I've noticed Google are using it for their main menu on the [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) site.

Comment: Note that you can also have multiple `<dt>` per `<dd>` and `multiple `<dd>` per `<dt>`. In your example, there can be more words meaning the same, and the same word(s) can have more meanings.

Answer (score 2):

When you're working with a set of definitions and not merely an list of unordered items.

Comment: what in person name then short description about person? and for question answers?

Comment: If it's a definition, use `dl`. It's merely a list, `ul`. The names are pretty self-explanatory. Granted, there will be some cases where it might be difficult to say which is best, but it's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

For ambiguous cases like your examples in the comment on Jonathan's answer (person name then description, question then answer), why don't you install a trial version of a screen reader or two and find out which construct is read most appropriately?

Here are two (from [here](http://www.webaim.org/techniques/screenreader/)):

- [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/fs_products/JAWS_HQ.asp)
- [Window Eyes](http://www.gwmicro.com/demo)